# How can i handle if int.TryParse(string, out int) can't fit the int, ie. they enter a really big number

Tags: c#, console, tryparse

I have this code to handle the event when the user enters a non-int string in a console application:

```
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        int num;
            while (!int.TryParse(input, out num))
            {                                 

                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a number, try again");
                input = Console.ReadLine();

            }
```

Ofc, it writes the same "Enter a number, try again" if they enter a really big number. I know i could change it to UI64 or other big integer, but you can still type a number too big for that. Is there a simple way to check either the TryParse or the num variable for this kind of overflow?

Comment: use `BigInteger`. you have to include `System.Numerics`.

Comment: What are you going to tell the user when it turns out the number is too big?  Just tell him what range is valid, like "Please enter a number between 0 and 100".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Int32.Parse` in a `try-catch` statement:

```
try {
    Int32.Parse(string);
} catch (System.OverflowException e) {
    // do stuff
}
// be sure to catch all other possible exceptions here
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx

The `TryParse` method already handles this kind of stuff internally, and doesn't allow you to catch exceptions manually. The `Parse` method **can fail** and will throw an exception, so you'll have to catch all other possible exceptions. See the above link for all other exceptions the method might throw.

The `OverflowException` occurs when the entered value is lower than `Int32.MinValue`, or higher than `Int32.MaxValue`.

Comment: you have to also catch other exceptions by adding another catch block at the end

Comment: Like I said in my answer, you'll have to catch all other possible exceptions. I'll clarify it some more.

Comment: i see. but a single line `catch { }` will satisfy. note that the order is improtant. it should be after catching overflow exception.

Comment: That would work indeed, but I consider it good practice to try and catch each exception specifically. It's not always necessary though, and in this case it would be sufficient if there is no need to discern between empty input or invalid format input.